# Java classpath jdbc issue

Tags: java, jdbc

I have run into crazy problem.

Below is my directory structure

```
 - src
       Sub - directory are
       - com/abc/www      MyJava.java (Contains the package com.abc.www)
 - lib
       It contains the jar files like sqljdbc4.jar
 - bin
       It contains the class file , that I had compiled the 
       package directory structure created automatically
       - com/abc/www/MyJava.class
```

I used the below line to compile my code :

```
java -cp "lib\*" -d bin src\com\abc\www\MyJava.java
```

It compiled successfully.

Well, now when I m trying to execute my code:
    cd bin
    java com.abc.www.MyJava

Unfortunately, it is giving me the below error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)
  ....
```

Any inputs on the same , would be helpful.

Thanks !!!!

Comment: give the -cp flag to the startup as well

Comment: java -cp "lib\*"  src\com\abc\www\MyJava for running the application.

Comment: nope , it shows , then it shows NoClassDefFoundException.

Comment: its lib\\*. the same command which you used for compiling but without the .java extn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
java -cp .;bin;lib\sqljdbc4.jar com.abc.www.MyJava
```